# Telethon, использование приватного прокси

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, telethon

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks
client = TelegramClient('session_id',
api_id=12345, api_hash='0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef',
proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'localhost', 4444))
```

Как использовать приватный прокси? В библиотеке указано чтобы использовать [PySocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks#installation) <- ссылка. Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
import socks
client = TelegramClient('session_id', api_id='12123123', api_hash='0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef', proxy=(socks.SOCKS5, 'ip-proxy', port-proxy, 'логин', 'пароль'))
```

Еще IPV6 - **НЕ РАБОТАЮТ**.
Надеюсь помогу кому-то с использование прокси.